# Puppet an Wso2 test for updating files

Tags: puppet, wso2-api-manager

I have installed Puppet 3.8(open source) and Wso2am-2.1.0
I have followed these links 
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/install_el.html#step-4-install-puppet-on-agent-nodes https://github.com/wso2/puppet-base/wiki/Use-WSO2-Puppet-Modules-in-puppet-master-agent-Environment

I have scenario to test wso2 and Puppet.
I have wso2am-2.1.0\repository\conf\datasources\master-datasources.xml file(working setup) and i don't want this file to be updated when i pull update from master.
Any Idea how can i achieve this ?
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a change in master-datasources.xml only , then puppet will update the file and start the service .

Please put your question in detail

Comment: Yes, There is change in master-datasorces.xml and i dont want to override this file.
I got the answer after some research , i will update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once after i have started working on wso2 i had couple of modification for configuration like carbon.xml, datasource.xml ,user-mgmt.xml and many more .
So if i use puppet with wso2 to take update then by default these files (carbon.xml, datasource.xml ,user-mgmt.xml) are getting modified.
And if you dont want to modify these files then modify /etc/puppet/hieradata/production/wso2/**common.yaml** file under below section

## Puppet template list to be populated

wso2::template_list:
.

You can even change the installation directory also by modifying the common.yaml.